# Find intersection between two arrays with restrictions

Tags: arrays, search, optimization, data-structures

I have to write a program in order to find the same numbers between two arrays.
The problem is that I have to do it in the most optimized way respecting some constraints:

-Having i,j indexes for the array A and w,x indexes for the array B, if A[i]=B[w] and A[j]=b[x]  and i

-The maximum distance between these numbers has to be k (given by input);

-I have to use at maximum O(k) space in order to implement something to optimize the search;

-The numbers appears only once in each array (like sets).

I was thinking about constructing a balanced RBTree with k elements of the first array in order to optimize the search process, but I am in doubt about the space it requires (I think it's not O(k) because of the pointers and the color marking).

Anyone has a better idea about this problem?

Edit: I'll put my examples here to make it more clear:

- Array A: 3 7 5 9 10 15 16 1 6 2
- Array B: 4 8 5 13 1 17 2 11
- Constant k = 6
- Output: 5 1 2

Edit2: In the output the numbers must appear in the same sequence as they are in the arrays.

Comment: What is the relationship between i and j ? (and w and x) What do you mean by "distance between these two numbers" ?

Comment: There is no relationship, they are two generic indexes for which we have that A[i]=B[w] and A[j]=B[x]. This is true for all common numbers found.
For distance between these two numbers I mean that assuming that we find a common number, the next common number will be at max at "index of the found number in the array" + k constant, and it will not be necessarily the same.
For example:

32 1 15 6 7 18 9 12 35  | 
10 2 1  5 8 21 22 7 101

 |  1 and 7 are common numbers, and are placed in the same order at a different distance, but, for example, are placed at a distance that is less than k=10.

Comment: Sorry, that is totally unclear to me. Maybe you could rephrase the questions a bit and/or add a numerical example + the desired result? UPD: I see you cannot update your Q yet. Maybe I should add your example to the OQ?

Comment: I have added the example to the OQ, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, thank you ;-) 
Is it more clear now? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Since you don't have any limits on the running time, you could probably just use a O(N*N) "windowed" search. (with a K sized window)

Comment: Unfortunately I have to keep the running time as low as possible, here's my problem.
Thank you for the answers, and forgive me for the english, It's not my native language ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using K as Max Distance

Assuming that when you say they must be presented in Array order that the order from one array is sufficient - assuming:

A: 1 2
B: 2 1

results in 1 2 or 2 1 and not either 1 or 2 since the ordering is crossed

Note that the K constraint makes this less optimal

The first observation is that anything in the larger array, past the index of the number of elements in the smaller array + K -1 can be ignored

The second observation is that all values are apparently `int`

The third observation is that this has to be optimal for huge arrays with a K that can be close to the size of the arrays

A radix sort is O(N) and takes O(N) size, so we will use that

In order to allow for K we can copy both arrays to parallel arrays of (value, position) and not copy values that are unreachable in the larger array as per observation 1 i.e.
A: 71, 23, 42 ==> A2: { 71, 0 }, { 23, 1 }, { 42, 2 }

We can also create a similar array for results that is the same size as the smaller array

We can modify the radix sort to move values and postions together

Algorythm:

```
1) Copy arrays [ O(1) ]

2) Radix sort array A and B by values [ O(1) ]

3) Walk A and B: [ O(1) ]
if A < B -> increment index in A
if A > B -> increment index in B
if A == B -> incremnt index in A and B
             add original A to result IF the pos diffence is less than K    
4) Radix sort results by position [ O(1) ]

5) print result values [ O(1) ]
```